# ts.plot() and dataFrame.plot() throwing error: " NameError: name '_converter' is not defined"

Tags: python, pandas, matplotlib, time-series

When running `plot()` method of a dataframe or series, python is throwing an error. Last line of the error is `NameError: name '_converter' is not defined`

I am using Python 3.6 and all other functionalities are working as expected so unsure what might be causing this.

Below is a code sample that causes the issue, and below that is the error that results.

```
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np
import matplotlib
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

ts = pd.Series(np.random.randn(1000), index=pd.date_range('1/1/2000', periods=1000))
ts = ts.cumsum()
ts.plot()
```

The error being returned is shown below:

```
NameError                                 Traceback (most recent call last)
<ipython-input-336-8fe4bd433d4d> in <module>()
----> 1 ts.plot()
      2 
      3 plt.plot(ts)

c:\users\fguih\appdata\local\programs\python\python36\lib\site-packages\pandas\plotting\_core.py in __call__(self, kind, ax, figsize, use_index, title, grid, legend, style, logx, logy, loglog, xticks, yticks, xlim, ylim, rot, fontsize, colormap, table, yerr, xerr, label, secondary_y, **kwds)
   2501                            colormap=colormap, table=table, yerr=yerr,
   2502                            xerr=xerr, label=label, secondary_y=secondary_y,
-> 2503                            **kwds)
   2504     __call__.__doc__ = plot_series.__doc__
   2505 

c:\users\fguih\appdata\local\programs\python\python36\lib\site-packages\pandas\plotting\_core.py in plot_series(data, kind, ax, figsize, use_index, title, grid, legend, style, logx, logy, loglog, xticks, yticks, xlim, ylim, rot, fontsize, colormap, table, yerr, xerr, label, secondary_y, **kwds)
   1925                  yerr=yerr, xerr=xerr,
   1926                  label=label, secondary_y=secondary_y,
-> 1927                  **kwds)
   1928 
   1929 

c:\users\fguih\appdata\local\programs\python\python36\lib\site-packages\pandas\plotting\_core.py in _plot(data, x, y, subplots, ax, kind, **kwds)
   1725                             pass
   1726                 data = series
-> 1727         plot_obj = klass(data, subplots=subplots, ax=ax, kind=kind, **kwds)
   1728 
   1729     plot_obj.generate()

c:\users\fguih\appdata\local\programs\python\python36\lib\site-packages\pandas\plotting\_core.py in __init__(self, data, **kwargs)
    929 
    930     def __init__(self, data, **kwargs):
--> 931         MPLPlot.__init__(self, data, **kwargs)
    932         if self.stacked:
    933             self.data = self.data.fillna(value=0)

c:\users\fguih\appdata\local\programs\python\python36\lib\site-packages\pandas\plotting\_core.py in __init__(self, data, kind, by, subplots, sharex, sharey, use_index, figsize, grid, legend, rot, ax, fig, title, xlim, ylim, xticks, yticks, sort_columns, fontsize, secondary_y, colormap, table, layout, **kwds)
     98                  table=False, layout=None, **kwds):
     99 
--> 100         _converter._WARN = False
    101         self.data = data
    102         self.by = by

NameError: name '_converter' is not defined
```

Comment: This seems to be a bug with your pandas version. Using pandas 0.20.1, the code is working as expected.

Comment: I got the same error. Probably not the solution you're looking for, but I downgraded my Anaconda environment to Python 3.5 and it worked fine.

Comment: If you are indeed using the newest pandas version, you may report this on [the pandas issue tracker](https://github.com/pandas-dev/pandas/issues). It is then either a bug in the code (it seems the code actually assumes that it may fail, as `from pandas.plotting import _converter` is put into a [`try/except` clause](https://github.com/pandas-dev/pandas/blob/1245f0673074316b53d1d1ee10abd6077058b133/pandas/plotting/_core.py#L45), but its not clear why.) or it is a missing update of the documentation.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can get this working if you snap your time series to a daily frequency before plotting, using `pd.Series.asfreq`:

```
ts.asfreq('D').plot(); 
plt.show()
```

[image]

Comment: thanks for that.  it would be good to know the issue though , as the code and example is from the pandas website, so i would assume it should work as expected.     :     http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/10min.html#plotting

Comment: @wilson_smyth For that one would first need to know which pandas version you are using.

Comment: pd.__version__ returns  0.22.0

Comment: Following the first example from http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/10min.html#plotting leads to this error. Please improve the answer and explain why you did what you did to get it working.

Comment: For those having the same issue (https://github.com/pandas-dev/pandas/issues/19340) try restarting your Python interpreter.

Comment: @nbkhope I understand where you're coming from, but this answer is more a "uh, I don't know what the problem is but this works for me" kind of answer. I know that's sorta bad, because it doesn't completely answer the question, and I've embraced that downvote. If you can help me out here as to why this works, I'd really appreciate that.

Answer (score 7):

Based on the comment of nbkhope:

> Restart you python interpreter

In my case, stopping and starting again `jupyter notebook`

(I took way too long to debug this issue so I'm posting this as an answer)

Answer (score 0):

Encountered the issue while using pandas 0.22.*
Updated to pandas 0.23.0.
The issue seems resolved.